# EmberJS 2.7 assertion failed passing id of nested object

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, htmlbars

EmberJS 2.7
Error:
Assertion Failed: `id` passed to `findRecord()` has to be non-empty string or number

**app/templates/products/index.hbs:**
[inside the model/each loop I have this line]:

```
{{#link-to 'categories.edit' product.category.id}}<a href="">{{product.category.name}}</a>{{/link-to}}
```

**app/router.js:**
[I have these routes defined]:

```
  this.route('products', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:product_id/edit' });
  });

  this.route('categories', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:category_id/edit' });
  });
```

It works when editing a product. But throws the above error when trying to edit a category.

If I delete the 'categories/edit' route and add this route instead:

```
this.route('category', { path: '/categories/:category_id/edit' });
```

and change the template to use that:

```
{{#link-to 'category' product.category.id}}<a href="">{{product.category.name}}</a>{{/link-to}}
```

Then it works. I understand why this second one works. **But why does the first one not work?**

**EDIT: Here are the models**

app/models/product.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', { async: true })
});
```

app/models/category.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('product')
});
```

Comment: "this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers" - I totally disagree with that. If you search SO you can see the particular error I quoted has many causes and for people new to EmberJS trying to discern what the cause of that error can be very difficult. I spent considerable wasted time myself reading them all and trying to find out what was throwing the error in my code. It's not a 'simple typo' when you put a full block of code into the wrong file and trigger this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Where you put the findRecord on the model is important. I had this code in the categories route. Moving it to the correct file solves the problem.

app/routes/categories.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('category', params.category_id);
    },
});
```

**SOLUTION**:

app/routes/categories.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

app/routes/categories/edit.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('category', params.category_id);
    },
});
```